# Robotframework: How to use Tabindex as locator?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I was hoping the community here could help me. I am stuck with a test case, for a rather simple input.
Problem is that on the webpage, I have two input fields that need to be populated. The CSS for both is similar. The only exception is the tab index values.

```
<input type="text" class=“text-dropdown-input-field " ag-class="getInputClass()" ag-keydown="inputKey($event, true, true, false, true)" tabindex="100">


<input type="text" class=“text-dropdown-input-field" ag-class="getInputClass()" ag-keydown="inputKey($event, true, true, false, true)" tabindex="120">
```

I am using this in the Robot file.

```
input text                  tabindex:100  ${val1}
input text                  tabindex:120  ${val2}
```

I fail here:

Message:    Element with locator 'tabindex:100' not found.

Is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: since `tabindex` is an attribute, have you tried `//input[@tabindex='100']`?

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do the trick! Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query for a tabindex the way you are doing it. `tabindex` is an attribute, so a simple xpath would be this:

```
//input[@tabindex='100']
```